# Python: Establishing List with List Comprehensions or Iterators

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, list-comprehension, python-itertools

I am am trying to improve my coding, and algorithm performance by replacing `for` loops with list comprehensions, generators, and iterators.

I am having a hard time rapping my head around how to implement the tools in `itertools`, and I would appreciate any help you could give.

I am trying to initialize an list with value `0` from for a certain range of indices. Here are two ways that I came up with:

```
count_list = [0 for index in range(4 ** k)]
```

and

```
total_index = list(range(4 ** k))
count_list = [0 for index in total_index]
```

(k represents an integer of the the number letter in a word made of a 4 letter alphabet)

When I timed the code in **Python 3.4**, it turned out that the first, using the generator was a significantly faster method when looking at it in isolation, however when I had to reuse the `4 ** k` index for another loop, the methods ended up timing at about the same speed.

What I have been struggling to figure out is how I can use an iterator to replicate this initialization. I know if I wanted to create a list of all of the numbers in the index I could just use `list(range())` or I could use

```
index_list = [index for index, values in enumerate(words)]
```

I am just not sure how to get it to assign the value `0` to each element using something like that.

I am also wondering how I might use list comprehension to get rid of this `for` loop. I am guessing I need something like map, but I am not sure how to implement.

```
for index in range(4 ** k):
    if frequency_array[index] >= t:
        clump[index] = 1
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To initialize your list with `0`:

```
>>> my_list = [0] * 10
>>> my_list
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

If you want to use `list` comprehension instead of `for` loop, you can do it this way:

```
>>>t = 3
>>>l = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,3,2,1]
>>>new_list = [1 if l[i] >= t else l[i] for i in range(len(l))]
>>>new_list
[1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1]
```

Also, you can use the `AND - OR` combination, this way:

```
>>>new_list = [l[i] >= t and 1 or l[i] for i in range(len(l))]
>>>new_list
[1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `[0] * 4**k` for initializing a list with zeroes.

Simple benchmark:

```
~/Dev/Python/test   python -m timeit '[0] * 1000'
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.15 usec per loop

~/Dev/Python/test   python -m timeit '[0 for index in range(1000)]'

10000 loops, best of 3: 41.9 usec per loop
```

Comment: Are you hungry? Or is that just an encoding issue?

Comment: What can I say, I like burgers!